# Send email to filtered data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I have data extension, I need to send email from another application hosted in cloud. Data extension have let say 100 records and I want to send email to only few records where some field = something and which return some let say 15 records.

So email goes to 15 records not to 100 records in that extension. I tried FuelSDK and cannot filter data extension before sending, some one suggested use soap api but still struggling to find the way to use soap for this purpose.

Please if some one have already done this , would you guide me the right way to achieve this.

Comment: What kind of email definition in SFMC?  Trigger?  UI Send?

Comment: Email send using FuelSDK or SOAP API

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Filtered DE with your criteria (some field = something). And then send to this filtered DE